Convertir una imagen tipo blob para verla en la web
Tengo una web con Python y flash y necesito tomar desde la base de datos en MySQL una imagen que está en formato blob. ¿Cómo poder convertirla para visualizarla?
<td>

    {% if(libro.Lib_Img !="") %}
    <img src="{{ libro.Lib_Img };base64}" class="sin_foto_mini" alt="{{ libro.Lib_Titulo }}">
    {% else %}
    <img src="sin_foto.jpg" class="sin_foto_mini" alt="imagen-Libro">
    

</td>



¿Es similar el caso?
